# Cocoa project without Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, makefile

I am writing a sample application on Mac OS X using Cocoa.

Things were fine when I was using Xcode to built and debug.

But when I started building by makefile, program is same, every file is same (as shown by diff), output is different.

My first question: Is this makefile to build a cocoa project correct?

Make file is:

```
CLANG   = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang

LINK    = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang 

ARCH    = x86_64    
MIN_VERSION = 10.8

DEBUG_PATH  = bin/debug

SYSROOT = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contests/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/

IBTOOL  = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool

SDK = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk

FRAME   = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

LIB = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib

FLAGS   = -g -O0

debug: $(DEBUG_PATH)/test.app

run:
    open $(DEBUG_PATH)/test.app

$(DEBUG_PATH)/test.app: $(DEBUG_PATH)/test
    cp $(DEBUG_PATH)/test $(DEBUG_PATH)/test.app/Contents/MacOS/test  
    cp  en.lproj/credits.rtf  $(DEBUG_PATH)/test.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj
    cp  en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings $(DEBUG_PATH)/test.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj
    cp PkgInfo $(DEBUG_PATH)/test.app/Contents/
    rm -f $(DEBUG_PATH)/test
    cp test-core-text-Info.plist $(DEBUG_PATH)/test.app/Contents/Info.plist
    touch $@

$(DEBUG_PATH)/test: $(DEBUG_PATH)/AppDelegate.o $(DEBUG_PATH)/main.o
    mkdir -p $(DEBUG_PATH)/test.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/en.lproj
    $(CLANG) -arch $(ARCH) -isysroot $(SYSROOT) -L$(DEBUG_PATH)/ -L$(LIB) -mmacosx-version-min=$(MIN_VERSION) AppDelegate.o main.o -framework Cocoa -o $@ -F $(FRAME)
    $(IBTOOL) --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile $(DEBUG_PATH)/test.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/MainMenu.nib en.lproj/MainMenu.xib --sdk $(SDK)

clean:
    rm -rf $(DEBUG_PATH)/test.app
    rm -f $(DEBUG_PATH)/*

$(DEBUG_PATH)/AppDelegate.o: src/AppDelegate.m
    $(CLANG) -arch $(ARCH) $(FLAGS) -Wall -c $< -o $@

$(DEBUG_PATH)/main.o:   src/main.m
    $(CLANG) -arch $(ARCH) $(FLAGS) -Wall -c $< -o $@
```

Output of Xcode (run app from anywhere)
[image]

Output by makefile

[image]

It is still conundrum to me that the program is same, Info.plist is same, nib is same, why the output is different.

What is the thing I am missing?

Comment: Did you check your version ??

Comment: Just curious : why would you not want to use Xcode ?

Comment: @hussainShabbir: How to do it?

Comment: In our build, we use makefile to build not Xcode.

Comment: Version means your os version is it same??

Comment: @hussainShabbir: Yes. It is same. 10.8.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding paths, use `xcrun clang`, `xcrun ibtool`, etc. Then your Makefile even when Xcode isn't installed in /Applications.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're writing a Makefile instead of using `xcodebuild`?